# Django: Using custom raw SQL inserts with executemany and MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, django, insert

I need to upload a lot of data to a MySQL db. For most models I use django's ORM, but one of my models will have billions (!) of instances and I would like to optimize its insert operation.

I can't seem to find a way to make executemany() work, and after googling it seems there are almost no examples out there.

I'm looking for the correct sql syntax + correct command syntax + correct values data structure to support an executemany command for the following sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO `some_table` (`int_column1`, `float_column2`, `string_column3`, `datetime_column4`) VALUES (%d, %f, %s, %s)
```

Yes, I'm explicitly stating the id (int_column1) for efficiency.

A short example code would be great

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a solution that actually uses executemany() !

Basically the idea in the example [here](http://www.smipple.net/snippet/adige/kinterbasdb%20executemany) will work.

But note that in Django, you need to use the %s placeholder rather than the question mark.

Also, you will want to manage your transactions.  I'll not get into that here as there is plenty of documentation available.

```py
    from django.db import connection,transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    
    
    query = ''' INSERT INTO table_name 
            (var1,var2,var3) 
            VALUES (%s,%s,%s) '''
    
    
    query_list = build_query_list() 
    
    # here build_query_list() represents some function to populate
    # the list with multiple records
    # in the tuple format (value1, value2, value3).
    
    
    cursor.executemany(query, query_list)
    
    transaction.commit()
```

Comment: Half a year late, but finally an answer regarding executemany(). I haven't tested your answer, but I'm accepting it and hoping your code works

Comment: I can't find documentation for a function buildQueryList() anywhere. Is it part of Django?

Comment: if you read the comments...it's up to YOU to build that function based on your application's specific needs / database schema...

#here buildQueryList() represents some function to populate
#the list with multiple records
#in the tuple format (value1,value2,value3).

Comment: For future people looking for the same thing: jsh's snippet works. Thanks

Comment: Note that if you are using MySQLdb 1.2 you'll run into a very unfortunate performance regression. The workaround is to use lowercase "values". Seriously. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945642/why-is-executemany-slow-in-python-mysqldb

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but how about some pythonic variable and function names? `query_list` instead of `queryList` and `build_query_list()` instead of `buildQueryList()`.

Answer (score 1):

are you serisouly suggesting loading billions of rows (sorry instances) of data via some ORM data access layer - how long do you have ?

bulk load if possible - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I think you missed where I wrote I'm using ORM for most models (which have only a few hundred of instances) and using raw SQL for the single model who has billions of instances, but the link is helpful thanks

Comment: Also, I can't really use load-data, as I do manipulate the data before I enter it to the db...

Comment: Lastly, yes, it's that important, even if it takes a few days to insert to the db. It's a one time operation (until the next time...)

Comment: why dont you write a Dump2CSV method which processs your instances and creates a series of .dat files which you can load into your db ?

Comment: So what I guess you're saying is that no matter what the modification on the data is, I should separate the loading process from the data manipulation part and load using load-data

Comment: if you have doubts perhaps run a few benchmarks with say 1 million rows loaded via django and the same using load data infile then work out how long it would take to load 1000 million rows...

Comment: I ran some benchmarks - separating the pre-processing and the loading almost doubled the loading time as most of the time was spent on hard drive access

Answer (score 1):

If you need to modify the data, bulk load with `load data` into a temporary table as is. Then apply modifications with an `insert into select` command. IME, this is by far the fastest way to get a lot of data into a table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use the executemany() command, but you can [use a single SQL INSERT statement to insert multiple records](http://www.desilva.biz/mysql/insert.html)