# Parsing XML and saving Large Data to Django DB

Tags: python, django, xml, database, postgresql

I have a Django function that takes in a Nessus file and then parses the data before saving it to the database, my Nessus file typically has about 30k rows and saving this to the database can take as much as 2 hours, I have tried using **bulk_create** but this breaks the code, meanwhile I use Django 1.11, is there a way I can speed up these large inserts to the database (**postgres**)

**Here is my code:**

```
def process_nessus_file(*args, **kwargs):
    process_obj = kwargs.get('file')
    context = kwargs.get('context')
    request = kwargs.get('request')
    file_obj = process_obj.first()
    file_path = file_obj.file.path
    context = etree.iterparse(
        file_path,
        events=('end', ),
        tag="ReportHost"
    )
    total_issues = 0
    detected_issues = 0
    undetected_issues = 0
    already_exist_issue = 0
    low_risk_count = 0
    medium_risk_count = 0
    high_risk_count = 0
    critical_risk_count = 0
    low_new_issue = 0
    medium_new_issue = 0
    high_new_issue = 0
    critical_new_issue = 0
    vul_history = []
    for event, elem in context:
        first_identified = None
        last_seen = None
        host = elem.get('name')
        logger.info('Processing issue for host : {}'.format(host))
        for child in elem:
            if child.tag == "HostProperties":
                for host_prop_tags in child:
                    if host_prop_tags.attrib['name'] == "HOST_START":
                        first_identified = host_prop_tags.text
                    elif host_prop_tags.attrib['name'] == "HOST_END":
                        last_seen = host_prop_tags.text
            if child.tag == "ReportItem":
                main_tags = child.attrib
                child_tags = dict()
                for ch_tags in child:
                    if ch_tags.text:
                        tag_text = ch_tags.text.strip()
                    else:
                        tag_text = ch_tags.text
                    child_tags[ch_tags.tag] = tag_text
                if child_tags.get('solution') and \
                    child_tags.get('solution') in ['n/a', 'N/A']:
                    child_tags['solution'] = ''
                plugin_output = child_tags.get('plugin_output')
                pluginid = int(main_tags.get('pluginID'))
                if plugin_output and (pluginid == 10107):
                    if re.search(BANNER_PATTERN, plugin_output):
                        banner_pattern = plugin_output.replace("{}".\
                            format(BANNER_PATTERN), "")
                        banner = banner_pattern.strip()
                    else:
                        banner = ''
                else:
                    banner = ''
                risk = child_tags.get('risk_factor')
                synopsis = child_tags.get('synopsis')
                description = child_tags.get('description')
                solution = child_tags.get('solution')
                protocol = main_tags.get('protocol')
                port = main_tags.get('port')
                pluginname = main_tags.get('pluginName')
                svcname = main_tags.get('svc_type')
                try:
                    host_type = get_host_type(host)
                    user_host = check_host_exists(host, host_type)
                    if user_host and not NessusData.objects.filter(
                        plugin_id=int(pluginid), host=host,
                        port=int(port), name=pluginname
                        ).exists():
                        try:
                            host_link_obj = Host.objects.get(
                            host=host
                        )
                        except Host.MultipleObjectsReturned:
                            host_link_obj = host.objects.filter(
                                host=host
                            ).first()
                        except Host.DoesNotExist:
                            host_link_obj = Host.objects.create(
                                host=host,
                                user_host=user_host
                            )
                        nessus_obj = NessusFile.objects.create(
                            user_host=user_host,
                            host_link=host_link_obj,
                            linked_file=file_obj,
                            plugin_id=int(pluginid),
                            risk=risk, host=host,
                            protocol=protocol, port=int(port),
                            banner=banner, name=pluginname,
                            svc_type=svcname,
                            description=description,
                            first_identified=first_identified,
                            last_seen=last_seen,
                            synopsis=synopsis,
                            plugin_output=plugin_output,
                            solution=solution
                        )
                        issue = "Issue with host {}, port {} and"\
                            " pluginID {} is added.".\
                            format(
                                nessus_obj.host, nessus_obj.port,
                                nessus_obj.plugin_id
                            )
                        NessusFileLog.objects.create(
                            linked_file=file_obj,
                            issue_type="new",
                            issue=issue
                        )
                        detected_issues = detected_issues + 1
                        if risk == 'Medium':
                            medium_new_issue = medium_new_issue + 1
                        elif risk == 'Low':
                            low_new_issue = low_new_issue + 1
                        elif risk == 'High':
                            high_new_issue = high_new_issue + 1
                        elif risk == 'Critical':
                            critical_new_issue = critical_new_issue + 1
                    else:
                        nessus_obj = NessusFile.objects.filter(
                            plugin_id=int(pluginid), host=host,
                            port=int(port), name=pluginname
                        ).first()
                        if nessus_obj and not nessus_obj.last_seen:
                            nessus_obj.last_seen = last_seen
                            nessus_obj.save()
                        issue = "Issue with host {}, port {} and"\
                            " pluginID {} is already exists.".\
                            format(host,port, pluginid)
                        NessusFileLog.objects.create(
                            linked_file=file_obj,
                            issue_type="duplicate",
                            issue=issue
                        )
                        already_exist_issue = already_exist_issue + 1
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
                if risk == 'Medium':
                    medium_risk_count = medium_risk_count + 1
                elif risk == 'Low':
                    low_risk_count = low_risk_count + 1
                elif risk == 'High':
                    high_risk_count = high_risk_count + 1
                elif risk == 'Critical':
                    critical_risk_count = critical_risk_count + 1
                total_issues = total_issues + 1
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
```

I heard using raw sql queries will speed it up but I cant wrap my head around the process

Comment: You are doing insertion with Django's own methods. You should try to do it with pure `SQL` functions like `INSERT INTO`. It will help you to insert multiple data into database, but be careful with it, it will not do execute any `save` or `signal` of django.

Comment: how do I do this please can you provide an example

Comment: Think link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6101536/7320045